# CRichEditCtrl from resource loads 1.0 instead of 2.0

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013, mfc, richedit

I'm trying to update my application to use RichEdit 2.0; it's been using 1.0 since forever. Per the Microsoft documentation, I've changed AfxInitRichEdit() to AfxInitRichEdit2(), and I changed the class in the resource file from RICHEDIT to RichEdit20A (which is correct for this application). There is only one richedit in the resource file.

The application fails when I try to do anything with the window that includes this richedit. The dialog creation fails somewhere inside of ::CreateDialogIndirect(), and although I put breakpoints in CRichEditCtrl::Create and also on the class I derive from it, those breakpoints do not trip.

Out of frustration I tried calling AfxInitRichEdit() again and also calling AfxInitRichEdit2(). The application works! The breakpoints I put in do trip--but only on controls I create dynamically, not the one from the resource file. And when I run Active Window Spy, I see that the richedit created from the resource file somehow has a class of RICHEDIT even though I explicitly said RichEdit20A, and yet the dynamic ones are RichEdit20A as intended.

_RICHEDIT_VER is 0x210, and I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

I just can't figure out why CreateDialogIndirect() is making a RICHEDIT control--or trying to make one and failing, if I don't call AfxInitRichEdit()--instead of a RichEdit20A in spite of explicit instructions to the contrary. Any ideas?

Comment: Why still RichEdit 2.0 and not [one of the newer versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787873(v=vs.85).aspx) (AFAIK RichEdit 4.1 is supported since Windows XP).

Comment: Hmm, you make a good point. I'm not sure where _RICHEDIT_VER is being set in the underlying code (AFAIK it's not anywhere in the project proper) so I might have to change that part of it, but it's worth looking into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I feel stupid. There's a script that runs as part of the build process to update some resources, and for some reason that script has sometimes gotten confused between the debug and release versions, and copied resources from the release build into the debug build. I don't know why that happens and it's an issue for another day, but the upshot is the .rc file I had changed was getting replaced with another one.

Building the release version with the changes, and then building the debug version again, solved the problem.